# "Powder detergent for washing machines are available." ---Is this grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

I believe that detergent is a mass noun.
Must it be "detergents" (with an s) if the verb is "are"?

Comment: Powder detergent for washing machines is available.  *For washing machines* is just a parenthetical to the detergent.  Use the single form.

Comment: To your question, yes, detergents with an 's' would take 'are':  *detergents are*

Comment: Both of the above comments are correct. Use ***either*** *detergent is* or *detergents are*. It can be a mass noun or a count noun, depending on what you are trying to convey.